# Ejecutar fichero python desde mi web php

Tags: php, python, python-3.x

¿Es posible ejecutar un programa python desde mi web mediante php?

Hice una pequeña prueba pero al ser el campo web un campo que no domino y tampoco saber si esto es posible, no se por donde tirar.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<HTML lang="es">

   <HEAD>
        <title> Prueba</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </HEAD>

    <BODY>
        <div>
            <form action="" method="post">
               <input type="button" name="botonPrueba" value="Ejecutar">
            </form>

            <?php
                exec('prueba.py')
            ?>

        </div> 
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Donde `prueba.py` es,

```
import os

# main
def main():
    os.mkdir("Libros")

# Ejecutamos la función main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

No hagais caso a la funcionalidad porque esto es solo una prueba de si se puede o no para luego hacer otras cosas con más coherencia y más elaboradas.

Leí que esto en teoría se hace mediante Django o Flask pero yo querría saber si se puede ejecutar un fichero python con php.

Saludos y gracias

Comment: Si se puede ejecutar un archivo python solo que tienes que saber donde esta ubicado y me imagino que tengas que llamar al interprete de python para ello

Comment: @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas en este caso los dos están ubicados en la misma carpeta, por eso no puse ruta en el exec

Answer (score 1):

Okey para responderte a tu pregunta necesitas varias cosas:

1. Tener tu ruta de python agregado en las variables del sistema
2. Tener tu servicio de apache corriendo bajo tu usuario actual, lo cual le da ciertos permisos como es el de ejecutar comandos.

Yo tengo Windows 10, no se cual seria tu caso pero podemos adaptarlo si lo necesitas.
Para el punto 1 necesitas ir a **Mi PC**, click derecho sobre **Este Equipo**, **Propiedades**, en el menú de la izquierda seleccionar **Configuración avanzada del sistema**, busca el botón **Variables de entorno** y le das click, a continuación, en la ultima lista buscas el elemento con el nombre de Variable **Path**, lo seleccionas y le das **Editar**, una vez lo tengas abierto, buscas en tu equipo donde radica la raíz de tu instalación d epython en mi caso estaba en **C:\Python27** por consiguiente añadi al cuadro de texto de la ventana comentada anteriormente **;C:\Python27** el **;** es para separar cada una de las entradas de esa variable. Una vez realizado esto click en Aceptar en todas las ventanas y ya estas dispuesto a probar si te funciona lo que hisites.

Presionas **Windows+R** y escribes cmd, una vez abierta la consola escribes **python --version**, presionas **Enter** y debe salirte la versión que estas empleando.

Bien ahora te restaría el segundo caso, tendrias que presionar **Windows + R**, escribes **services.msc** y presionas **Enter**. Cuando te salga la ventana buscas el servicio de apache en mi caso era **wampapache64**, lo seleccione y di doble click, te paras en la pestaña **Iniciar sesión**, seleccionas la casilla **Esta cuenta** y escribes tu contraseña de tu usuario. Aceptar y reinicias el servicio.

Una vez hecho esto ya puedes ejecutar archivos de python, solo destacar que para ejecutarlos debes pasar primero el interprete es decir si deseas ejecutar un archivo llamado **prueba.py**, deberá ser **python prueba.py**. Aqui abajo te dejo mi ejemplo del código.

**Archivo de python: prueba.py**:

```
import os

def main():
    os.mkdir("Libros")
    print('directorio creado')

main()
```

**Archivo de php: index.php**

```
<?php

   echo shell_exec('python prueba.py');
```

Y una vez navegue por mi url en el navegador a ese archivo se creara la carpeta "Libros", ojo si ya existe esa carpeta lanzara un error y no se creara la carpeta, para que lo sepas por si neesitas seguir con esa idea...

Si estas bajo un sistema operativo unix o linux aqui te dejo unos links para que puedas hacer los 2 primeros pasos:

https://www.kroatoan.es/trucos-y-solucines/cambiar-usuario-se-ejecuta-apache/
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1002214/how-to-add-python-path-in-ubuntu-16-04